# Checking which variable threw exception

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception

Is there a way to check which variable assignment method threw an exception? For example:

```
a = '\xa1'
b = 'normal string'

try:
    c = b.encode('ascii')
    d = a.encode('ascii')
except Exception as e:
    print "error thrown for input: %s" % <figure out which variable threw error>
```

In this case, I'd want the output to say "error thrown for input: d" whereas if I switched the variables so that c = a.encode('ascii') then the output would say "error thrown for input: c". Would this be possible or would I need to separate the variable assignments into two different try blocks?

Also, out of curiosity, let's say it was 5, 10, or more variables that aren't easily iterated with a for loop. Would that be 5-10 different try blocks? Or would you pile them into a list just for a for loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A variable never throws an exception. The exception is thrown from the *method* `encode` being called.

If you want to know what threw the exception, wrap each `encode` call in a separate `try/except` block.

You could also take a look at `e`:

```
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

The output for `\xa1` is:

```
'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xa1' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

There you see the offending input.

**Edit:**

You can also take a look at `e.args` which for `\xa1` is:

```
('ascii', '¡', 0, 1, 'ordinal not in range(128)')
```

So `e.args[1]` is the offending input.

Comment: Alright so I believe I worded it incorrectly in trying to simplify my problem. I know that the variable wouldn't throw the exception but I want to know which line did this and output a more user friendly message than the one you gave. I have a system where users are supposed to input data and if they have errors it will display a message on where to fix it. A message like that isn't going to help them that much which is why I wanted to pinpoint which one would have given the exception to output in a user friendly message and if I really needed multiple try/catch blocks.

Comment: @JarrettPhillips You can check `e.args`. I've edited my answer.

Comment: That's pretty useful, although I don't like how it doesn't directly tell me which variable it was supposed to be assigned to, I could compare e.args[1] with the inputs to see which one it was.

Answer (score 1):

**Note: don't try this at home kids, readability counts**

```
a = '\xa1'
b = 'normal string'
z = 0
try:
    c = b.encode('ascii')
    z = 1
    d = a.encode('ascii')
except Exception as e:
    print "error thrown for variable %s" % (a if z else b)
```

You can create a temporary variable, let's call it z, set it to 0, if an exception didn't happen for the b variable then change z to 1, finally check if z == 1, if yes, then the encode method in the second variable had threw the exception, if not then the encode method in the first variable was the one who threw the exception, I think this code works well, but I didn't test it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [traceback](https://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html#traceback.format_exception_only) module to get more info:

```
a = '\xa1'
b = 'normal string'
import sys, traceback
try:
    c = b.encode('ascii')
    d = a.encode('ascii')
except Exception as e:
    exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()
    traceback.print_tb(exc_traceback)

File "/.............py", line 65, in <module>
d = a.encode('ascii')
```

`traceback.print_tb(exc_traceback)` gives you the line number and the offending variable.

To get the reason:

```
print("Reason: {}".format(e.reason))
Reason: ordinal not in range(128)
```